# Javascript Replace via RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am trying to replace 3 chars with 3 other chars to build/mask an email address for a form.

This works only once or on the first instance of finding it:

```
email = "email1#domain!com|email2#domain!com|email3#domain!com";
email.replace("#","@").replace("!",".").replace("|",",");
```

The above code resulted in: email1@domain.com,email2#domain!com|email3#domain!com

After some reading I read about using RegEx which is the portion of coding I can never wrap my head around:

```
email.replace("/#/g","@").replace("/!/g",".").replace("/|/g",",");
```

That didn't work either and left it the same as the original var.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not put quotes around the regex. Regexes are literals that use `/` as a boundary.

Additionally, you will need to escape the `|` because it has a special meaning.

Finally, `.replace` is not transformative. It returns the result.

```
email = email.replace(/#/g,'@').replace(/!/g,'.').replace(/\|/g,',');
```

Comment: Thanks - will accept this answer when I can in a few minutes!

Answer (score 1):

Using [regex literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), you omit the quotes (and you'll need to escape the pipe):

```
email.replace(/#/g,"@").replace(/!/g,".").replace(/\|/g,",");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
email = "email1#domain!com|email2#domain!com|email3#domain!com";
email=email.replace(/#/g,"@").replace(/!/g,".").replace(/\|/g,",");
```